# I am new in dagger 2 how to achieve that?

Tags: android, retrofit, mvp, dagger-2

**This is MVP Module**

```
@PosterFragmentScope
@Module
public class PosterFragmentModule {

    PosterFragmentMVP.View view;
    Context mContext;

    public PosterFragmentModule(PosterFragmentMVP.View view,Context mContext) {
        this.view = view;
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @PosterFragmentScope
    @Provides
    public PosterFragmentPresenter providePresenter(PosterFragmentMVP.View view , PosterFragmentMVP.InterActor interActor){
        return new PosterFragmentPresenter(view,interActor,mContext);
    }

    @PosterFragmentScope
    @Provides
    public PosterFragmentMVP.View provideView(){
        return view;
    }

    @PosterFragmentScope
    @Provides
    public PosterFragmentInteractor provideInteractor(APIServices.TMDbPopular tmDbPopular,APIServices.TMDbServiceTopRated tmDbServiceTopRated){
        return new PosterFragmentInteractor(tmDbPopular,tmDbServiceTopRated);
    }

    @PosterFragmentScope
    @Provides
    public PosterFragmentMVP.Presenter providePresenterInterface(APIServices.TMDbPopular tmDbPopular,APIServices.TMDbServiceTopRated tmDbServiceTopRated){
        return providePresenter(view,provideInteractor(tmDbPopular,tmDbServiceTopRated));
    }

    @Provides
    @PosterFragmentScope
    Context provideContext() {
        return mContext;
    }

    @Provides
    @PosterFragmentScope
    public PosterAdapter provideAdapter(){
        return new PosterAdapter(mContext,new ArrayList<Movie>());
    }

    @Provides
    @PosterFragmentScope
    public APIServices.TMDbPopular provideTmDbPopular(Retrofit retrofit){
        return retrofit.create(APIServices.TMDbPopular.class);
    }

    @Provides
    @PosterFragmentScope
    public APIServices.TMDbServiceTopRated provideTmDbServiceTopRated(Retrofit retrofit){
        return retrofit.create(APIServices.TMDbServiceTopRated.class);
    }
}
```

**This API Module**

```
 @Module
@Singleton
public class APIModule {

    private final String BASEURL = "https://api.themoviedb.org/";

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public OkHttpClient provideClinet (){
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();

        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        return new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public Retrofit provideRetrofit(String base_url, OkHttpClient okHttpClient){
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(base_url)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    @Provides
    public APIServices.TrailersService provideTrailersService() {
        return provideRetrofit(BASEURL, provideClinet()).create(APIServices.TrailersService.class);
    }

    @Provides
    public APIServices.ReviewsService provideReviewsService() {
        return provideRetrofit(BASEURL, provideClinet()).create(APIServices.ReviewsService.class);
    }
```

**This Is APP Component**

```
 @Component(modules = {RoomModule.class,APIModule.class})
@Singleton
public interface APPComponent {
    PosterFragmentComponent plus(PosterFragmentModule posterFragmentModule);
    MovieDetailComponent plus(MovieDetailFragmentModule movieDetailFragmentModule);
}
```

**This Is poster Component**

```
@Subcomponent(modules =PosterFragmentModule.class)
@PosterFragmentScope
public interface PosterFragmentComponent {
    void inject(PosterFragment posterFragment);
}
```

When i make this give me that **error**

> Error:(19, 8) error: [com.example.ali.moviedb.DI.Components.PosterFragmentComponent.inject(com.example.ali.moviedb.Views.PosterFragment)] java.lang.String cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides-annotated method. java.lang.String is injected at com.example.ali.moviedb.DI.Modules.APIModule.provideRetrofit(base_url, …) retrofit2.Retrofit is injected at com.example.ali.moviedb.DI.Modules.PosterFragmentModule.provideTmDbPopular(retrofit) com.example.ali.moviedb.Contracts.APIServices.TMDbPopular is injected at com.example.ali.moviedb.DI.Modules.PosterFragmentModule.providePresenterInterface(tmDbPopular, …) com.example.ali.moviedb.Contracts.PosterFragmentMVP.Presenter is injected at com.example.ali.moviedb.Views.PosterFragment.presenter com.example.ali.moviedb.Views.PosterFragment is injected at com.example.ali.moviedb.DI.Components.PosterFragmentComponent.inject(posterFragment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I solved this by Make My API Module like this

```
 @Module
@Singleton
public class APIModule {

    private final String BASEURL = "https://api.themoviedb.org/";

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public OkHttpClient provideClinet (){
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();

        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        return new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public Retrofit provideRetrofit(OkHttpClient okHttpClient){
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASEURL)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
```

> Is There best solution for that

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're not injecting `Retrofit` instance directly so shouldn't need that provides (specific error seems to be that it can't find something to inject for `base_url` parameter).  You should be able to change to something like:

```
public Retrofit createRetrofit(String base_url, OkHttpClient okHttpClient){
    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(base_url)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
}
@Provides
public APIServices.TrailersService provideTrailersService() {
    return createRetrofit(BASEURL, provideClinet()).create(APIServices.TrailersService.class);
}

@Provides
public APIServices.ReviewsService provideReviewsService() {
    return createRetrofit(BASEURL, provideClinet()).create(APIServices.ReviewsService.class);
}
```

Comment: the error appear when i add this in my poster module when i try provide top rated service

Comment: @AliShawky did you try the changes above? (should not be any annotations for `createRetrofit`)

Comment: this what i do in my API Module

Comment: i try your changes and give my the same error the error is because i create api service into my poster fragment module

Comment: It worked when i remove BASEURL from provide retrofit method